# using alternate kernel in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: kernel, alternate

I am facing this boot crash issue (along with several other people), and have failed to resolve this using various fixes/solutions available online(in numerous forums/blogs)

**Kernel Panic - Not Syncing : Fatal exception in Interrupt**

But my analysis have concluded that this is a kernel issue which happens with newer versions of ubuntu kernel 3.8.0-21+ versions and not a driver issue of GFX, broadcom, alsa etc

Question is can I use any other kernel with my ubuntu 13.04 like the main kernel or some alternative/custom kernel or install older versions of generic ubuntu kernel say 3.2 or 3.8.0.0 types

I use synaptic to install/remove kernels but the oldest version it shows to which i can downgrade to is 3.8.0.19 which also causes problems but frequency is less, with 3.8.0.26/27 it crashes everytime I boot.

Comment: i am not looking to upgrade kernel, the problem is with upgrade only, i wish to downgrade it or use non ubuntu kernel

Comment: You can follow the same method to use any kernel do you wish.

Comment: all kernel versions are compatible with 13.04 ? even older versions that is unlikely

Comment: that similar post doesnot say anything about NON-UBUNTU kernels

Comment: This because "NON-UBUNTU" kernels are off-topic on this site.

Comment: As a note, I'm not sure if there are NON-UBUNTU kernels and UBUNTU kernel. There are [Linux kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) and [non-Linux kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(computing)).

Comment: using kernel 3.9 solved the fatal exception issue. i wonder why 3.9 was not released while 3.10 is the current version.

Comment: The current version is 3.8. The others are in development.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu [Being about a custom kernel does not make a question off-topic for Ask Ubuntu.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5576/do-custom-kernels-constitute-off-topicness)